# C#: ATM System using Windows Form How do I fix withdraw button? The money is deducted twice

Tags: c#, button, polymorphism, abstract-class, windows-forms-designer

For example: when I have 200 in my balance and I withdraw for the first time 12$, the remainder is 188$(This works) but When I withdraw again 2$ (it must be 186)but the answer I get is 174$.
I used polymorphism and abstract classes in my project. I did debug it and found that the foreach statement i created is the problem but I couldn't fix it.
I forgot to put the database class

```
public class BankDatabase
{
    private Account[] account;
    public BankDatabase()
    {
        account = new Account[3];
        account[0] = new Account(1000, 1111, 200, 100);
        account[1] = new Account(1001, 2222, 400, 500);
        account[2] = new Account(1002, 3333, 100, 700);
    }
    private Account GetAccount(int account_number)
    {
        foreach (Account currentAccount in account)
        {
            if (currentAccount.AccountNum == account_number)
                return currentAccount;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public bool Validation(int user_accnum, int user_pin)
    {
        Account user = GetAccount(user_accnum);
        if (user != null)
            return user.verification(user_pin);
        else
            return false;
    }
    public decimal GetAvailableBalance(int user_accum)
    {
        Account user = GetAccount(user_accum);
        return user.AvailableBalance;
    }
    public decimal GetTotalBalance(int user_accum)
    {
        Account user = GetAccount(user_accum);
        return user.TotalBalance;
    }
    public decimal Credit(int user_accum, decimal amount)
    {
        Account user = GetAccount(user_accum);
        return user.Credit(amount);
    }
    public decimal Debit(int user_accum, decimal amount)
    {
        Account user = GetAccount(user_accum);
        return user.debit(amount);
    }
}  


class Account
{
    private  int accountnum;
    private int pin;
    private decimal availablebalance;
    private  decimal totalbalance;

    public Account()
    {

    }
    public Account(int accountnum, int pin, decimal availablebalance, decimal totalbalance)
    {

        this.accountnum = accountnum;
        this.pin = pin;
        this.availablebalance = availablebalance;
        this.totalbalance = totalbalance;
    }
    public int  AccountNum
    {
        get
        {
            return accountnum;
        }
    }
    public int PIN
    {
        get
        {
            return pin;
        }
    }
    public decimal AvailableBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return availablebalance;
        }
    }
    public decimal TotalBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return totalbalance;
        }
    }

    public decimal Credit(decimal amount)
    {
        return availablebalance = availablebalance + amount;
    }

    public decimal debit(decimal amount)
    {
        return availablebalance = availablebalance - amount;
    }

    public bool verification (int userpin)
    {
        return (userpin == PIN);
    }
}

public class Withdraw : Transaction
{
    private decimal amount;
    decimal t2;
    public Withdraw()
    { }
    public Withdraw(int accountnum, BankDatabase database, decimal amount) : base(accountnum, database)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return amount;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Withdrawn amount is= " + t2;
    }
    public override decimal balance()
    {
        decimal availablebalance = DataBase.GetAvailableBalance(accountnum);
        if(amount<=availablebalance)
        {
            t2 = DataBase.Debit(accountnum, amount);

        }
        return t2;
    }       
}


public abstract class Transaction
{
    protected int accountnum;
    private BankDatabase database;
    public Transaction ()
    {

    }
    public Transaction(int accountnum,BankDatabase database)
    {
        this.accountnum = accountnum;
        this.database = database;
    }
    public int AccountNum
    {
        get
        {
            return accountnum;
        }
    }
    public BankDatabase DataBase
    {
        get
        {
            return database;
        }
    }
    public abstract decimal balance();
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Account Number" + accountnum;
    }
}

private void withdraw_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        transaction.Add(new Withdraw(Form1.accountnumber, database, with_amount));
        foreach (Transaction trans in transaction)       
        {     
            label2.Text = "Withdraw" + trans.balance().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're probably not clearing your transaction and your foreach loop is repeating it. Haven't looked through the code fully, but if you clear your transaction at the end of the method you should be good.

Comment: What is the datatype of the _transaction_ variable inside that withdraw_Click event handler? Is this a `List<Withdraw>`?  Where do you define it? You have shown us a lot of code but probably you have not shown the most important part

Comment: I will say that having Withdraw.Balance() seems like an odd place to apply the change. I would have expected Transaction to have a virtual Apply() or similar. And Account to have a Credit (for which a debit is merely a negative value) and Withdraw would rely on Account to actually make a change. A balance simply does not seem 'part' of a withdrawal.

Comment: @gilliduck I did use the  clear transaction and it works fine! Thank you!

Comment: Now I want to transfer money between accounts, is that possible without using a real database not a database class?

Comment: Made my comment an answer so you can accept it since it resolved your issue. For anything further, you'd need to create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your foreach loop you are iterating through your transaction without clearing it for the next loop. In effect you are stacking up transactions and repeating them each time. Clearing out `transaction` in some manner should resolve your issue.